# End of period averages - column vs row totals

Tags: excel, pivot-table, dax

I have a requirement to calculate averages for agreements for the average consumption as of the end of any given point-in-time.  Where they do not have have an entry in my `Agreement Data` table for the last day of the period, they should show as blanks.  The average should be an average of all agreements for that end-point-in-time.  Illustration of current output with desired output annotated.  In the below example, Agreements 1 and 2 ended before the 31st of December in 2015 and 2016 respectively.

[image]

Desired output:

[image]

The DAX is have is below, and I think I get that the Row totals are showing the `LASTNONBLANK()` value, however for Agreements 1 & 2 they would ideally show as blank as blank as they are not active as at 31 December 2016:

```
Average Consumption:=
CALCULATE(
    AVERAGEX('Agreement Data','Agreement Data'[ConsumptionPercentage])
    ,LASTNONBLANK('Calendar'[ActualDate]
            ,CALCULATE(
                AVERAGEX('Agreement Data','Agreement Data'[ConsumptionPercentage])
                )
            )
    )
```

Any ideas gratefully received. The relationship from `Agreement Data` to `Calendar` is on a `DateKey` column in both tables.

***I would also add that the years are also part of a year/month/day hierarchy along the top, so I'd want this principle to work if I drilled down to a day level.***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can make it quite a bit simpler. Try something like this:

```
Average Consumption :=
IF( LASTDATE( 'Agreement Data'[DateKey] ) < LASTDATE( 'Calendar'[DateKey] ),
    BLANK(),
    AVERAGE( 'Agreement Data'[ConsumptionPercentage] )
)
```

If your columns are a hierarchy of the calendar table, then the last date for whatever period you've drilled to should be `LASTDATE('Calendar'[DateKey])` whereas the last transaction date for that period is `LASTDATE('Agreement Data'[DateKey])`. If these don't match then, throw a blank, otherwise average the percentages.

---

**Edit:** In response to your comment...

If `DateKey` isn't a date format, then you can probably use `MAX` instead of `LASTDATE` or else use a column that is a date format.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  All results went blank however.  Also, as noted in the question it can form part of a date hierarchy so would need to behave in the same way if drilled down to date level.

Comment: The `DateKey` columns are numeric so can't work with `LASTEDATE()`.

Comment: Hi - I Added a related column called `ActualDate` to `Agreement Data` based on `'Calendar'[ActualDate]` and used your formula which appears to have worked.  If you add that info to your answer I can marked as ansswered. Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, my final code ended up as below.  The `LASTNONBLANK()` was still needed to only run averages on the final day of whatever sliced period there was, but was a hybrid between my original proposal and the marked answer.  This assumes your Calendar table only goes as far as you need it to:

```
Average Consumption:=
IF(MAX('Agreement Data'[DateKey]) < MAX('Calendar'[DateKey]),
BLANK(),
CALCULATE(
    AVERAGEX('Agreement Data','Agreement Data'[ConsumptionPercentage])
    ,LASTNONBLANK('Calendar'[ActualDate]
                ,CALCULATE(
                    AVERAGEX('Agreement Data','Agreement Data'[ConsumptionPercentage])
                        )
                    )
    )
)
```